# FileUtils.copyUrlToFile is not working

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I have fairly basic question i'm trying to download a PDF from this URL using java:

```
http://kundservice.svd.se/ui/templates/HttpHandler/PDFTidningen/PDFTidningen.ashx?date=2014-07-27&file=SVD_D_BILAGA_2014-07-27.pdf&mac=92267fcd3c75feff13154ba66870a523&free=True
```

here is my code "very basic":

```
public class Main {

private static final String PATH = "C:\\project\\DownloadTest\\src\\main\\resources\\tmp\\";
private static final String FILENAME = "data.pdf";
private static final String SvDPDFURL = "http://kundservice.svd.se/ui/templates/HttpHandler/PDFTidningen/PDFTidningen.ashx?date=2014-07-27&file=SVD_D_BILAGA_2014-07-27.pdf&mac=92267fcd3c75feff13154ba66870a523&free=True";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    File file = new File(PATH + FILENAME);
    URL url = new URL(SvDPDFURL);
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
 }
}
```

the problem is that file is empty, what i'm i doing wrong.

Comment: why do you have HTTP parameters on the end of the URL?

Comment: @ScaryWombat What's wrong with HTTP parameters?

Comment: I did not say that anything was wrong with it.

Comment: Have you tried the version FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File, int, int) which allows you to specify timeouts etc

Comment: cant really answer why the URL parameter is there, this Isn't it my site (the site belongs to Sweden´s third largest newspaper). JamesB could you explain how the timeout works ?

Comment: if your system is *nix just call wget

Comment: ensure that a read-only 0 byte file does not previously exist

Comment: what does `Du har ej access` mean?

Comment: "Du har ej access" means that "you do not have access"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it `https` instead of `http`.

```
https://kundservice.svd.se/ui/templates/HttpHandler/PDFTidningen/PDFTidningen.ashx?date=2014-07-27&file=SVD_D_BILAGA_2014-07-27.pdf&mac=92267fcd3c75feff13154ba66870a523&free=True
```

It is happening because there is a redirect when you hit the url. It redirects to https. Browsers get the response and the response code is 302 then redirects to the given url but the `FileUtility` can not handle that.

To confirm use `firebug` or `chrome developers tool` by hitting `F12` and go to `Network` tab.

Comment: I think you should change your questions title to something generic like, FileUtils.copyUrlToFile is not working or 0 size file.